# Where do Azure wcf service Trace.WriteLine requests go?

Tags: wcf, azure

I have looked at a lot of different Azure and Wcf service examples.  I have configured a trace listener and much trace information is appearing in the associated log file; however, I don't see the results of my Trace.WriteLine requests.  I do see my Trace.WriteLine requests in the Azure debugger output panel..  Where is the output of these requests persisted?

From my Web.config

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source propagateActivity="false" name="System.ServiceModel"
    switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="AzureLocalStorage">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Information">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="AzureLocalStorage">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add type="WCFServiceWebRole1.AzureLocalStorageTraceListener, WCFServiceWebRole1"
    name="AzureLocalStorage">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true" />
```

From my AzureLocalStorageTraceListener.cs

```
    public class AzureLocalStorageTraceListener : XmlWriterTraceListener
{
    public AzureLocalStorageTraceListener()
        : base(Path.Combine(AzureLocalStorageTraceListener.GetLogDirectory().Path, "WCFServiceWebRole1.svclog"))
    {
    }

    public static DirectoryConfiguration GetLogDirectory()
    {
        DirectoryConfiguration directory = new DirectoryConfiguration();
        directory.Container = "wad-tracefiles";
        directory.DirectoryQuotaInMB = 10;
        directory.Path = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("WCFServiceWebRole1.svclog").RootPath;
        return directory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **AzureLocalStorageTraceListener** you created simply logs to a *.svclog file. If you want to output logs to the emulator there are a few things you should take care of:

1. Add the DevelopmentFabricTraceListener to your shared listeners (this will also work for the 1.7 SDK)

   ```
   <add type="Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.DevelopmentFabricTraceListener, Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Emulator">
     <filter type="" />
   </add>
   ```
2. Make sure the switch value is correct (you could try the value **All** to get started)
3. Change the logging level in the emulator (by right clicking the icon at the top right of the screen).

[image: Change Logging Level]